Are there any formal models of belief-formation processes?
I'm considering how one could create a precise, mechanistic model of belief-formation, especially one with predictive testability. It could be based on an ontology of "knowledge", including categories like "supports prior beliefs", "affirms social identity / group inclusion / decreases cognitive dissonance", "appeals to a sense of the truth coming from a trusted party or from an adversary of a distrusted party", "serves to benefit the believer in view of some incentive", and in some way describe what argumentative structures appeal to people's sense of reason (maybe a way of quantifying how close an argument is to "fully formal", to characterize how "flexible" an argument has to be for someone to find it logically sound); the ontology would not describe all people's belief-formation equally, but would characterize different belief-tendencies by arrangements of the concepts in the ontology - i.e., different thinking-styles or even "epistemic 'personalities'".
Are there prior examples of anything similar?

There are formal approaches to modelling belief formation and revision, but what you are describing there is particularly complex and detailed and I'm not sure how feasible it would be. There is some information in the SEP article on formal representations of belief and also in the article on formal epistemology.
